# AutoCAD VB.Net Color Picker

Tags: autocad

I am porting some AutoCAD VBA to VB.Net.

Several of the modules do a `ThisDrawing.SendCommand("_color" & vbCR)` to popup an AutoCAD color picker, then process the response by doing a `ThisDrawing.GetVariable("CECOLOR")` to get the selected color.

With .Net, the SendCommand does not execute until the program ends.

How can I get the AutoCAD color picker to execute inline in my code?

Answer (score 2):

There is a ColorDialog class to do that. Here is some C# code:

```
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Windows;

var cd = new ColorDialog();    
if (cd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
ed.WriteMessage("\nSelected color: " + cd.Color);
```

Comment: Thw Autodesk.AutoCAD.Windows.ColorEditor is exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks!